# Openssl need to use CA bundle file (Intermediate cert)

Tags: c++, openssl, ssl-certificate

I just purchased a SSL certificate from Go Daddy.
Great price, but it seems that it has a draw back.

It seems to need the bundle.crt in order to work correctly on must browser.
I'm not yet really sure what it is, from what I have understand it is an intermediate certificate from Certificate Authority. Correct me if I'm wrong
So in my software I have openssl

```
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(SSL_ctx, pem_passwd_cb);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(SSL_ctx, _private_key, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(SSL_ctx, _certificate, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(SSL_ctx, "./ssl_key/bundle.pem");
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(SSL_ctx,SSL_SESS_CACHE_SERVER|SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL);
SSL_CTX_set_quiet_shutdown(SSL_ctx, 1);
```

The error I get is :

**You didn't run init properly or an error occured.**

With lasts certs (geotrust) I didn't need the bundle intermediate, I'm really lost here.

Since SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file accepts only PEM files, I have converted the bundle.crt file to PEM using openssl.

Any idea ?

Thanks!

EDIT 1 : 
Apparently Intermediate certificate must be on the /etc/ssl/certs folder.
I have putted every intermediate certificate from go-daddy on this folder, and still no luck...
I have removed the line

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(SSL_ctx, "./ssl_key/bundle.pem");
```

Which seems to be no use for me here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after testing one million things I finally found out.

I didn't convert the bundle.crt into PEM.
I have pasted the certificate file directly in the bundle.crt (at the beginning of the file)

I have removed this line on my code :

```
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(SSL_ctx, _certificate, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

So here's the final code for SSL init :

```
SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(SSL_ctx, pem_passwd_cb);
SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(SSL_ctx, _private_key, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(SSL_ctx, "./ssl_key/bundle.crt");
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(SSL_ctx,SSL_SESS_CACHE_SERVER|SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL);
SSL_CTX_set_quiet_shutdown(SSL_ctx, 1);
```

Hope this helps someone, and save them a lot of time (1 full day for me ;-))